# cUrl запрос с конкретного интерфейса

Tags: c++, linux, curl

Имеется ОС Linux, libcurl 7.68.0, 2 интерфейса с доступом в 2 разных подсети.

```
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 enp0s31f6
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    103    0        0 enx00a0c6000000
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     103    0        0 enx00a0c6000000
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     102    0        0 enp0s31f6
```

Из с++ кода, с помощью cUrl и опции **CURLOPT_INTERFACE** делаю Get запрос на внешний домен, но запрос почему-то не выполняется. **CURLOPT_VERBOSE** показывает следующее:

```
*   Trying %корректный.внешний.ip.адрес%:443...
* Name '192.168.0.2' family 2 resolved to '192.168.0.2' family 2
* Local port: 0
* Connection timed out after 15001 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
* Hostname %нужный-домен.ком% was found in DNS cache
*   Trying %корректный.внешний.ip.адрес%:443...
* Hostname 192.168.0.2 was found in DNS cache
* Name '192.168.0.2' family 2 resolved to '192.168.0.2' family 2
* Local port: 0
* Connection timed out after 15001 milliseconds
* Closing connection 1
* Hostname %нужный-домен.ком% was found in DNS cache
*   Trying %корректный.внешний.ip.адрес%:443...
* Hostname 192.168.0.2 was found in DNS cache
* Name '192.168.0.2' family 2 resolved to '192.168.0.2' family 2
* Local port: 0
* Connection timed out after 15000 milliseconds
* Closing connection 2
```

И так повторяется без конца.

```
curl_easy_setopt(this->Curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "192.168.0.2"); // пробовал так
curl_easy_setopt(this->Curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "enx00a0c6000000"); // и так тоже
```

Если установить 192.168.0.1 шлюзом по умолчанию и сделать запрос, то запрос выполнится успешно. Так же успешно выполняется запрос если  в **CURLOPT_INTERFACE** указать адрес из текущей подсети по умолчанию или вовсе убрать эту опцию. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: не смущает Hostname %нужный-домен.ком% was found in DNS cache? попробйте для начала по ip обращаться

Comment: Найден в кэше. Адрес же пишет корректный и по прямому ip та же беда.

Comment: пардон. прочитал неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

а если так

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://...."); 
  if(curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "if!enx00a0c6000000")==CURLE_INTERFACE_FAILED) printf("oops...");
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

> If the parameter starts with "if!" then it is treated as only as
> interface name and no attempt will ever be named to do treat it as an
> IP address or to do name resolution on it. If the parameter starts
> with "host!" it is treated as either an IP address or a hostname.
> Hostnames are resolved synchronously. Using the if! format is highly
> recommended when using the multi interfaces to avoid allowing the code
> to block. If "if!" is specified but the parameter does not match an
> existing interface, CURLE_INTERFACE_FAILED is returned from the
> libcurl function used to perform the transfer.

если не сложно приведите рабочий кусок кода, попробовать воспроизвести

Comment: if! и host! пробовал. Ваш код запустил в чистом проекте, вот результат: https://hastebin.com/raw/hidirinini

Comment: чтобы исключить свою ошибку попробуйте сделать запрос самой утилитой курла (curl --verbose --interface enx00a0c6000000 -X GET "....") и второй момент. попробуйте запустить запрос с sudo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066407/how-to-use-curl-on-specific-interface)

Comment: странно, так работает. почему даже в чистом проекте не работает - не понятно...

Comment: все, понял, бинарник с судо запускать нужно

Comment: причем работает только с интерфейсом, адрес и так не работает, но это я уже переживу

Comment: благодарю за помощь!